# Symfony DIC | Add new Extension to parse new keyword in config file

Tags: php, dependency-injection, symfony

I try adding a new keyword ('ressources') in coonfig file of Sf-DIC like 
 => array('imports', 'parameters', 'services'))

Based on \Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\YamlFileLoader::validate, i have try to register new extension into container with BundleClass. For :

```
 <?php if (!$this->container->hasExtension($namespace)) { // l.429
```

BUT

When i register my extension like that :

```
    <?php 
    $extension = new ApiResourceExtension();  
         // getAlias(){ return 'resources';}

    $container->registerExtension($extension);
    $container->loadFromExtension($extension->getAlias());


    $extension = new ConfigurationExtension();
    $container->registerExtension($extension);
    $container->loadFromExtension($extension->getAlias());
```

I see in var_dump on vendor, when hasExtension test, No extension is registred into container...

Obliviously an error occure : here is no extension able to load the configuration for "resources"

Why Container hasn't extension when play Extension::load Method. How can i pass through to get my behavior ?

Thanks. 
Alborq

Comment: Adding the extension at the Bundle level probably fails because how the Compiler works. Try to set up your extension in a [CompilerPass](http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/compiler_passes.html)